# Error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. Connection string is correct

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I get this error every time when i perform "update-database" command in packet management console. I'm totally sure that my connection string is correct, but i keep getting an error.
Connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "NewConn": "Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=*******;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
```

Fragment af code that calls it out:

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
var connStr = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("NewConn");
builder.Services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(connStr));

The connected db is connected, i copied its connection string.
If anybody got a solution, i would be very thankful.

I tried to change a bit the calling method, but i assume that's not the case.

Comment: JSON requires escaped backslashes - as you've censored-out the `Data Source=` value we can't see if you're using a named-instance or not - but if you are, then it should be like `Data Source=(local)\\SQLEXPRESS` and not `Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem, but thanks for the advice. I use name of the pc as a data source

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution. In my DbContext i added another function that was trying to connect using this connection string that was written with mistakes. So if anyone get the same error: check all of the functions that have to use your connection string

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

In my frontend, for my sql data source, I had this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlData" runat="server"  ConnectionString="DBConn" SelectCommand="stproc_ClientBulkUpload_Select" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

which threw the error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.", so to fix that, I just had to change the `ConnectionString` value from `"DBConn"` to `"<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConn %>"`

Hope this helps!